# Seaborn barplot with some complexity

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataframe with a target column (binary) and a categorical column that I'd like to evaluate, and see for each category the percentage of observations there are grouped by the target (for example, category "a" presents a column indicating that it has 23% of the positive event, and 10% of the negatives, both staked in the same bar).

Now the problem is that I'd like to also evaluate different dataframes together, and have a column for each dataframe. I have already concatenated all of them in a single dataframe so I can use hue in Seaborn, but I can't pass the multi index from the group by.

This is a small example of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "a"], "target" : [0,1,1,1,0,1], "frame" : ["test", "test", "train", "train", "test", "train"]})

a = df.groupby(["frame", "col", "target"])["target"].count()
a = a / a.groupby(level=0).sum()
a
```

In the groupby I'm trying to create a dataframe that could have all the values I need to use Seaborn, but I cannot get pass this :(

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reset_index` to be able to use the columns:

```
a.rename('value').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   frame col  target     value
0   test   a       0  0.333333
1   test   b       0  0.333333
2   test   b       1  0.333333
3  train   a       1  0.666667
4  train   b       1  0.333333
```

Note however that [seaborn doesn't do stacked barplots natively](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1485), so you'll either need to use pandas plotting or change the type of plot.